# AFNetworking User Login asynchron issue

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, afnetworking-2

When the user presses the button Login, the login-post request will be send.
Then I want to fetch the result from this post request, whether it was successful or not.

My Post-request:

```
func login (username: String, password: String) -> Bool {
    var param = ["username": username, "password": password]
    POST(APIURL.URL_LOGIN, parameters: param,  
       { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, response : AnyObject!) -> Void in
            println("Login")
        self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "USERLOGGEDIN")
        }, { (operation : NSURLSessionDataTask!, error : NSError!) -> Void in
            self.defaults.setBool(false, forKey: "USERLOGGEDIN")
        })

    if (self.defaults.boolForKey("USERLOGGEDIN") == true) {
        return true
    }
    else if (self.defaults.boolForKey("USERLOGGEDIN") == false) {
        return false
    }
    else {
        return false
    }
}
```

My button call:

```
@IBAction func login(sender: AnyObject) {
    var username: NSString = userid.text
    var userpassword: NSString = password.text

    //Loginroutine
        var flag = (_sharedAPIManager.login(userid.text, password: password.text)) as Bool

        if ( flag == true) {
           println("correct password")
        } else {
            println("false password")
        }
    }
}
```

I have to press the login buttons sometimes twice.
I think this issue is related to afnetworking using different threads.

How can I solve this issue in an elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't because AFN is using different threads, it's because you aren't dealing with the fact that it is (and you asked it to) properly. That's because your loving method:

> `func login (username: String, password: String) -> Bool {`

is returning a `Bool`, but when it returns the asynchronous login won't be complete.

Instead of returning `Bool` your function should take a completion block which is called with a `Bool` parameter, and it should be called from the AFN `success` and `failure` blocks (because that's when you know the result status of the login).

So your login method would be:

```
func login (username: String, password: String, completion: ((success: Bool) -> Void)!)
```

and in the POST response you would have:

```
println("Login")
self.defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "USERLOGGEDIN")
completion(true)
```

Comment: Could you write some lines of code?
Then I will understand your concept more easily.
Could I also solve this problem with NSNotificationCenter?

Comment: You could do it with notifications but that probably wouldn't be ideal (unless lots of controllers in the app needed to know about the login event).